# How document snapshot works

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application where we can upload images to firebase real time database.

[image: question.png]

In the image we can see that the email is after a uuid.

Now I added the following code:]

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addChildEventListener(object :ChildEventListener{
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                val email= snapshot.child("email").value as String
                emails.add(email)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

If we want to get to the email we must follow this path: `user->uuid->email`(here uuid is string of random letters and numbers)

but in code we have used `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")` and then used `snapshot.child("email")` which is used to get `email`.

My question is why have we followed path `users->email`. We have nowhere mentioned about going to the uuid?

How will the database locate `email` if we haven't given which `uuid` it should locate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. What part of the code you shared isn't working as you expect/intent it to work?

Comment: My code is working. I had a doubt, that's why I asked

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I have edited the question. The code is working fine, I am not understanding how its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attach a listener with `addChildEventListener` to a location, its `onChildAdded` method is called by every child under that location. So the Firebase SDK calls your `onChildAdded` for UID under `/users`.